# Finding $F(x)$ given $F(2x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Could someone explain why if,

$$G(x) = -F(2x)$$

Given $G(x) = x^2$, $F(2x) =-x^2$ then $F(x) = -\frac{1}{4}x^2$

I dont understand why its $\frac{1}{4}$ instead of $\frac{1}{2}$

Thank you

Comment: $(\tfrac12)^2 = \tfrac14$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ F(x)=-G(x/2)=-\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2=-\frac{x^2}{4} $$

Answer (score 1):

$F(x)=-\frac{1}{4}x^2$ so $F(2x)=-\frac{1}{4}(2x)^2$ or $F(2x)=-\frac{1}{4}\times 4 \times x^2$.

Can you see why? the $4$ cancels.

Comment: $F(x)\neq -x^2$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* Since $F(2x)=-x^2$ make the substitution $y=2x$ and see what happens.